# 'System.Xaml' which was not found in the GAC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

Trying to update Microsoft.Build.Framework using Nuget in my SLN and getting the below error. This is VS 2017 Enterprise Version 15.9.1
Projects all target NET461 in this sln.

I duplicated this problem on 2 different windows 10 machines with the same project.

What can I do to get these packages updated?

**Output**

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.15.8.166' with respect to project 'Synovia.Service', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'
Gathering dependency information took 3.08 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.15.8.166' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.15.8.166'
Resolved actions to install package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.15.8.166'
Found package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework 15.8.166' in 'D:\git\sbss\Source\packages'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.tasks.core/15.7.179/microsoft.build.tasks.core.15.7.179.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.utilities.core/15.7.179/microsoft.build.utilities.core.15.7.179.nupkg
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core 15.7.179' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core 15.7.179' from 'nuget.org'.
Found package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.Interop 1.16.30' in 'D:\git\sbss\Source\packages'.
Removed package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.15.6.82' from 'packages.config'
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.utilities.core/15.7.179/microsoft.build.utilities.core.15.7.179.nupkg 53ms
Installing Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core 15.7.179.
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.tasks.core/15.7.179/microsoft.build.tasks.core.15.7.179.nupkg 78ms
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.15.6.82' from Synovia.Service
Installing Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core 15.7.179.
Removed package 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.15.6.82' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.15.6.82' from Synovia.Service
Removed package 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.15.6.82' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.15.6.82' from Synovia.Service
Package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.15.8.166' already exists in folder 'D:\git\sbss\Source\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.15.8.166' does not exist in project 'Synovia.Service'
Package 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.15.6.82' already exists in folder 'D:\git\sbss\Source\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.15.6.82' to 'packages.config'
Package 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.15.6.82' already exists in folder 'D:\git\sbss\Source\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.15.6.82' to 'packages.config'
Package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.15.6.82' already exists in folder 'D:\git\sbss\Source\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.15.6.82' to 'packages.config'
Executing nuget actions took 6.84 sec
Failed to add reference. The package 'Microsoft.Build.Framework' tried to add a framework reference to 'System.Xaml' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the package. Please contact the package owners for assistance.
  Reference unavailable.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:10.1224742
========== Finished ==========
```

Comment: This package seems to be dependent on Visual Studio release (version number matching), so in your case you get a mismatch (15.8 package vs. 15.9 VS). You might have to wait till Microsoft ships 15.9 package). Such bites Microsoft itself too, as projects like DocFX always break when VS updates come. To get a definite answer, post to MSBuild https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues

Answer (score 1):

> 'System.Xaml' which was not found in the GAC

Your project is probably target `.Net 3.5`, which does not have this DLL. You can update the framework version in Project Properties.

If above not resolve your issue or you do not want to change your framework version, you can manually add the reference `System.Xaml` to your project:

Go to **References** -> **Add Reference...** and then click on **Browse**..

Add the file, which is located on (Windows 10): `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll`

Then update your nuget package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated my questions to specify I'm targeting NET461.

Comment: @Wjdavis5, Manually add reference `System.Xaml` not help?

Comment: TBH I haven't tried. I'd rather understand why the tooling is failing to work in a desirable way. Put another way, I dont care about reaching an end goal of upgrading the package, I just need to make sure that Nuget is operational.

Comment: Just like Lex said the package does not match the latest VS version. You can report it to the team:https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues